# How to play elite dangerous on manjaro linux

Tags: elite-dangerous, linux, elite-dangerous-horizons

I have just recently switched to Linux and I can't find a way to run elite on Linux so far. Does anybody have any solutions for this?

Comment: Is Wine still a thing? To be clear, I know nothing about it outside of hearing it being used to run Windows applications in Linux.

Comment: @Ellesedil wine still is a thing but it doesn't run elite because of the .net framework I think

Comment: Check out this thread: 

https://forums.frontier.co.uk/threads/how-to-install-ed-on-linux-using-wine-experimental-not-officially-supported.366894/

And the wiki posted at the top:

https://github.com/redmcg/wine/wiki/Wine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from ProtonDB:

> You have to instal dotnet472
>
> `$ protontricks 359320 -q dotnet472 win7`
>
> This takes about 30 minutes with a lot of error messages. After it
> finishes you have to make modifications to config files in the game
> directory, from both:
>
> /steamapps/common/Elite Dangerous/EDLauncher.exe.config
>
> /steamapps/common/Elite Dangerous/HardwareReporter.exe.config
>
> Delete the following line: `supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"`
>
> and add the following: `supportedRuntime version="v4.0"`
>
> Windowing: Activating Fullscreen After changing resolution, change the
> option to fullscreen mode. After a few tries it should work.

https://www.protondb.com/app/359320

Note: I have not personally tried this, but the above page is about the most useful reference for this you're going to find. It does very much seem to be distro-dependent, but those on Arch-based distros appear to be having much better luck than others.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Native steam 'play on linux' does not work, as it does not install mono, which is a framework Elite uses for the launcher.

This is how you could do it:

- Using latest version of Antergos Linux
- Using Lutris to install Windows Steam version of Elite Dangerous

(Lutris uses Wine, which autodetects the requirement of mono and installs everything required)

According to mzry, a user on the Frontier Forums, it runs as smooth as windows, and sound, audio, and joysticks work perfectly.

Hope this helps!